# How to check if a number in a range is present in a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have strings that contain an employees badge number (they start at 1000) and a score out of 10:

```
'9999 got a score of 7'
'9999 7'
'7 9999'
'employee 9999 was very good and I give them a score of 7'
```

I am able to extract the badge number:

```
my_string.split.find do |badge_number|
 Employee.exists?(badge_number: badge_number.to_i)
end
```

How can I extract the score out of 10?

Comment: Is it standard to not provide reasons for a down vote? I'd love to be able to learn from my 'mistakes'

Answer (score 4):

Given that the strings you are working with always have the same format, I'd use the [`String#scan`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-scan) method:

```
string = '9999 got a score of 7'
badge_number, score = string.scan(/\d+/)

badge_number
# => "9999"
score
# => "7"
```

Comment: `bagde_number` != `badge_number`

Answer (score 1):

If the string format never changes and you always want the last number, I'd use a very simple pattern of:

```
my_string = '9999 got a score of 7'
my_string[/(\d+)$/, 1] # => "7"
```

To convert that to an integer:

```
my_string[/(\d+)$/, 1].to_i # => 7
```

If you want both numbers, use `scan` like @toro2K recommended.

---

Regarding your code:

```
my_string = '9999 got a score of 7'
my_string.split.find do |badge_number|
 Employee.exists?(badge_number: badge_number.to_i)
end
```

Ugh. Don't do that. Here's what you're asking Ruby to do:

```
my_string = '9999 got a score of 7'
my_string.split # => ["9999", "got", "a", "score", "of", "7"]
```

Converting those values to integers results in:

```
my_string.split.map(&:to_i) # => [9999, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7]
```

So, for every word found when you `split` the string, you're asking Ruby to do a search in your database, or container, for badge numbers. *Luckily* (as opposed to doing it by design), the first one you want is a badge number, and is returned by `to_i` allowing `find` to be satisfied and fall through. If your string format was different you'd be beating up your database or code. If the string changed format, and the score was first, or you had a badge #0, your code would return false results.

---

Finally, you might want to reconsider using an integer field for your badge numbers. Do you intend to do math on the values? If not, why force your code to convert to integers? Is it conceivable a badge number could actually start with a zero (`0`)? Using an integer field will cause leading zeros to be trimmed. I'd recommend using a string value instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression for that:

```
result = my_string.match(/(\d+) got a score of (\d+)/)
```

You can then use `result[1]` and `result[2]` to get the badge number and score.

The `(\d+)` part of the regular expression matches for at least one digit.

Answer (score 0):

You are using this wrong. `split` will return an array. Using `find` on it turns it in an enumerator then you search for each element in the array (every word and number from your string).

What you could do:

```
badge_number = my_string.split.first.to_i
score = my_string.split.last.to_i
```

and then use those vars. (This assuming that the string has this information always in the same place)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Regexp#=~`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-7E)

> If `=~` is used with a regexp literal with named captures, captured strings (or nil) is assigned to local variables named by the capture names.

```
my_string = '9999 got a score of 7'
/(?<bagde_number>\d+)\D+(?<score>\d+)/ =~ my_string
bagde_number  # =>  "9999"
score  # => "7"
```

Comment: `[^0-9]` can be better written as `\D`.